# "一人にせず"? Meaning

Tags: grammar, translation

お前も私も一人にせず、且つお前に 少しの 罰を 与える 方法を考えてみた。

In this phrase I've some doubt about "一人にせず". Using google, I can translate it as "not alone". But I read "せず" is a negative form of "する” and indicate that one action took place without or in the absence of another action. But... It seems senseless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence makes perfect sense.

Structure: "I have thought about a method that would achieve "Primary Goal" while satisfying "Condition/Prerequisite"."

Primary Goal = お前に少しの罰を与える = "giving you a little punishment"

Condition/Prerequisite = お前も私も一人にせず = "without having to leave you or myself alone"

Comment: Thank you! I'm studiyng japanese, but there are a still a lot of things I need to learn.

Answer (score 2):

`一人にする` means "leave (smb.) alone". So `一人にせず` could mean "without leaving alone" or "not remaining alone".

To suggest a good translation for your quote we need more context.

Comment: Thank you >_<
The whole discourse the guy is doing was:

お前はあまりにも脆いた。
お前はやはり私のような強いものの後ろに隠れていなくてはな。だが。。。
私は反抗的な者が嫌いでな。
お前も私も一人にせず、且つお前に 少しの 罰を 与える 方法を考えてみた。

Before this, he was arguing with the other about their loneliness and he injures him seriously.